# Vb to c# conversion confusion - directCast and MyBase.Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, type-conversion

converting vb to c#  , what will be the best equivalent in c# of  this

```
<ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey:=True, IsRequired:=True)> _
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return DirectCast(MyBase.Item("name"), String)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                MyBase.Item("name") = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

Comment: try this - http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its return type string, just convert it to string. try the below code.

```
[ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
public string Name 
{
  get { return (string)base["name"]; }
  set { base["name"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: will DirectCast same work will be done by Casting like this ? (string)base["name"];

Comment: @tripathy definitely we can do directcast like this

Comment: With the limited original code snippet, you can't say for sure that the base class has an indexer or a method called "Item" - but it's probably a correct guess.