# Application_BeginRequest - call base method first

Tags: c#, iis, base-class

I have this working method in VB:

```
Public Overrides Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e)
```

How do I call the base method in C# in this method?

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: `base.Application_BeginRequest`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vb to c# conversion confusion - directCast and MyBase.Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227951/vb-to-c-sharp-conversion-confusion-directcast-and-mybase-item)

Comment: When i try : base.Application_BeginRequest, I get error : HttpApplication does not contain a definition for Application_BeginRequest

Comment: Then there is no base method to call - so no need to make the call.

Comment: There are some compiler magic to hook your code to `BeginRequest` event of `HttpApplication` class, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpApplication.cs,797 but generally speaking there is nothing in the base to call.